# Is "Fisher's LDA" the same as "Bayesian LDA for 2 classes"?

Tags: classification

Fisher's LDA for 2 classes uses within ($S_W$) and between ($S_B$) variances and the solution we want to find is just the first eigenvector of $S_W^{-1} S_B$. For more than 2 classes, it naturally goes to the same fashion.

For Bayesian LDA (classifying $x$ to the class which has the highest posterior probability given $x$), we use (as I know) the linear discriminant function for each class. And for 2 classes, the coefficient for $x$ in the decision boundary of Bayesian LDA ($(\mu_1 - \mu_2)^\top \Sigma^{-1}$) is the same (or constant-times) as Fisher's approach. Moreover in R, lda()$scaling is that coefficient or constant-times.

I checked the coefficients for 3 classes,
the coefficients of Bayesian LDA decision boundary which is ($\mu_k - \mu_j)^\top \Sigma^{-1}$ is not constant-times of Fisher's coefficients.
In R, lda()$scaling is the same as Fisher's approach, but is different from the Bayesian decision boundary coefficients.

So my question is:
"Only for 2 classes, Fisher's coefficients are the same as Bayesian LDA's decision boundary coefficients. And for more classes they are different."
Is this right?

Or I'll appreciate any comments on my thinking.